# display details of data in different component with help of its id in present component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

service.ts

```
getAuthors() {
    this.authors=[{
      name:'raj',
      authorid:'3e32233edd222221'
      },{
      name:"roje",
      _id:"3e3223"
      }];
  }
  getBooks() {
    this.books=[{
      name:'2states',
      lang:'english',
      bookid:'123333',
      authorid:'3e32233edd222221'
      }];
  }
```

app.comp.html

```
<a *ngFor="let book of books">
  <p>{{book.name}}</p>
  <p>{{book.lang}}</p>
  <p>{{book.authorid}}</p> <!--this author id -->
  <p>{{author.name}}</p><!-- i need to show name with help 
  of authorid present in book -->
  </a>
```

In Above html i was displaying book details.I need author name to display with help of its id
here is my setup https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-859us9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a map of authors, which allows `authorid` based access to author's object:

```
this.authorMap = this.authors.reduce((map, author) => {
  map[author.authorid] = author;
  return map;
}, {});
```

Now you can use this map in your template to render author's details:

```
<p>{{book.authorid}}</p>
<p>{{authorMap[book.authorid].name}}</p>
```

Comment: what if the author vaiable change after sometime in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to get specific author:

**In Conponent:**

```
getSpecificAuthor(id){
    const result = this.authors.filter(author => author._id == id);
    if(result){
      return result[0]['name']
    }else{
      return 'no name'
    }
  }
```

**In html:**

```
<a *ngFor="let book of books">
  <p>{{book.name}}</p>
  <p>{{book.lang}}</p>
  <p>{{book.authorid}}</p> <!--this author id -->
  <p>{{getSpecificAuthor(book.authorid)}}</p>
</a>
```

[**Here is the working slackblitz URL**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m4jmrq)

Comment: `this.authors.filter` will loop over the `authors` each time the method is called, which is quite inefficient.